# How do I swap 2 different images? Is my way a good practice?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple question, I have the solution for it but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it.

I have 2 images with no classes, no id's and I can't edit the markup. I need to swap the 2 images around using jQuery. This is literally thats all on the site.

```
<div class="content">
  <img src="images/img1.png" />
</div>
<div class="content">
  //some content
</div>

<div class="content">
    <img src="images/img2.png" />
</div>
```

The way I did it was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content:first').after($('.content:last'));
  $('.content:last').after($('.content:first'));
});
```

Now this works, but I assume its not the best way. Can anyone care to point me into the right direction please.

Thanks

Edit: I only have 2 pictures, I would like to swap the places of both of them. There are no other images, so img2 is in place of img1 and img1 in place of img2.

Comment: actually moving the same image twice. Once the first is moved to last..it becomes last...then next move is to move last (which was first) to after first...which is where it already is

Comment: _'I assume its not the best way.'_ - why?

Comment: Are you sure "*[that] works*"? Because, like charlieftl, I suspect that's moving the same image twice.

Comment: Hi guys, I can understand that I am moving the same thing twice, but it is the only way I was able to get img1 from the left to the right and img2 from the right to the left. Like I said, Im sure this isn't the right way, so I would like to know how I can do it the proper way

Comment: if it's working keep it ...what is expected results?

Comment: In any programming language, you need 3 variables to swap two or more values. Create a temporary variable to store the first one, set the first one to the last, and set the last to the temporary. If that doesn't make sense, I can write out some code for you.

Comment: @Jason: That isn't close to being true: `A = A+B; B = A-B; A = A-B;`

Comment: Actually in Javascript you don't need 3 variables. Just use `$('.content:first').before($('.content:last')); $('.content:last').before($('.content:first'));` and you are good. Or what the OP did, just in another order.

Comment: @Jason rarely does that apply to  DOM manipulation

Comment: @ScottHunter good point but that only works with some variables. I'd be surprised if that would work with JavaScript objects. That said, they used `before` and `after` functions, so, I'm a bit fuzzy on what the original poster's goal was.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9xdndepp/?

Comment: @charlietfl really? I'm curious how it handles that properly. More reason to believe JavaScript runs on black magic.

Comment: @Jason: In a nutshell: The DOM relies on identifyable elements. So swapping can be done by just assigning 2 elements a new place.

Comment: Depends on the case. In this case it wouldn't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the html contents using jquery, then simply reverse them

```
var img1 = $('.content:first').html();
var img2 = $('.content:last').html();
```

Then swap them

```
$('.content:first').clear();
$('.content:last').clear();
$('.content:first').html(img2);
$('.content:last').html(img1);
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what this does as I'm not 100% familiar with JS

Comment: there is no `clear()` method. If that is intended to be `empty()` it is totally redundant since `html()` as setter replaces contents

Comment: @llkzz this stores the html content in the objects img1 and img2, then you can set the content of the html by using them as parameters in .html()

Answer (score 0):

If you had images ABCDE, the first statement will change it to BCDEA, and the second will change *that* to BACDE, which swaps the first two (if that's what you want; you aren't clear on that point).

If you only have 2 images and want to swap them, your first statement will do the job.

Comment: I assume in his working piece of code he has the order the other way around. Then it works.

Comment: @ImreNagy: Since it wasn't specified *which* images need to be swapped, its hard to know what *right* is, much less how to code it.

Comment: Well the OP described that he has 2 images. So I just assumed he wanted to swap them ;) With "the order rhe other way around" I meant his code `$('.content:last').after($('.content:first')); $('.content:first').after($('.content:last'));` works.